# Change detection in data from webservice with Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

My web application periodically fetches data from various different remote web services. The data (array of JSON objects) mostly stays the same, but minor changes and additions/deletions to that array can happen.

The objective is to keep a local database that is up to date with the fetched data. However, I also need to know which objects were modified, added or deleted whenever updating the local database.

Using Hibernate (and assuming nobody else modifies the database), what would be a good strategy to implement this? Would it be a good idea to keep a checksum column for identifying modifications? Table sizes can be up to a few 100 000 rows, but only around 10 000 rows are updated at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Hibernate interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events) to gain access to the previous and new property state, but depending on your use case, it might be better to use a CDC solution like [Debezium](https://debezium.io/).